# algorithm to get first, second, third neighbors from a coordinate

Tags: c#, image, algorithm, image-processing

In a bitmap for each pixel, I'm trying to get its first, second, third... level of neighbors until the end of the bitmap, but my solution is a little slow, so let me know if any of you guys have a better algorithm or way to do this:

[image: example]

```
private IEnumerable<Point> getNeightboorsOfLevel(int level, Point startPos, Point[,] bitMap)
{
    var maxX = bitMap.GetLength(0);
    var maxY = bitMap.GetLength(1);
    if (level > Math.Max(maxX, maxY)) yield break;

    int startXpos = startPos.X - level;
    int startYpos = startPos.Y - level;
    int sizeXY = level * 2;

    var plannedTour = new Rectangle(startXpos, startYpos, sizeXY, sizeXY);
    var tourBoundaries = new Rectangle(0, 0, maxX, maxY);

    for(int UpTour  = plannedTour.X; UpTour<plannedTour.Width; UpTour++) 
        if (tourBoundaries.Contains(UpTour,plannedTour.Y)) 
            yield return bitMap[UpTour,plannedTour.Y];

    for(int RightTour  = plannedTour.Y; RightTour<plannedTour.Height;RightTour++)
        if (tourBoundaries.Contains(plannedTour.Right,RightTour)) 
            yield return bitMap[plannedTour.Right,RightTour];

    for(int DownTour  = plannedTour.X; DownTour<plannedTour.Width;DownTour++)
        if (tourBoundaries.Contains(DownTour,plannedTour.Bottom)) 
            yield return bitMap[DownTour,plannedTour.Bottom];

    for (int LeftTour = plannedTour.Y; LeftTour < plannedTour.Height; LeftTour++)
        if (tourBoundaries.Contains(plannedTour.X,LeftTour)) 
            yield return bitMap[plannedTour.X,LeftTour];

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the Nth level of neighbor if the pixel P is closer than N to an edge? Do you want to report just the pixels that are in bounds?

Comment: yes for your question but being more specific
 im triying to find the nearest pixel that has the same color.

Comment: You could use Min and Max to clip your plannedTour to the tourBoundaries up front, allowing you to eliminate the `if (tourBoundaries.Contains(...` check inside the loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if this is too slow, you might want to change your approach.

For example, generate a `Dictionary<Color, List<Point>>` which for each color in the bitmap has a list of points which are that color.   Then when you are given a point, you get the color and then run through the list of points to find the closest one to the given point.

This is a 1 time pre-compute on your image, and then changes the complexity to by the number of points which are the same color.  I'm assuming currently it is slow because you have to look at a lot of points because it is rare to find a point with the same color.

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed things is to make your `plannedTour` include the boundaries. For example:

```
var plannedTour = new Rectangle(
    Math.Max(0, startPos.X - level),
    Math.Max(0, startPos.Y - level),
    Math.Min(maxX, startPos.X + level),
    Math.Min(maxY, startPos.Y + level));
```

That pre-computes the boundaries and prevents you from having to check at every loop iteration. It can also save you an entire `Left` tour, for example.

If you do that, you need an `if` statement to prevent checking an area that is outside the boundaries. For example:

```
if (plannedTour.Y >= minY)
{
    // do Up tour.
}
if (plannedTour.X <= maxX)
{
    // do Right tour
}
if (plannedTour.Y <= maxY)
{
    // do Down tour
}
if (plannedTour.X >= minX)
{
    // do Left tour
}
```

A minor optimization would be to eliminate the four extra pixels you're checking. It looks to me as though you're checking each corner twice. You can prevent that by making the Left and Right tours start at `plannedTour.Y+1` and end at `plannedTour.Bottom-1`.

You might be able to save some time, although it'll probably be small, by using a strict left-to-right, top-to-bottom check. That is, check the Up row, then on the next row check the left and right pixels, then the next row, etc., and finally check the bottom row. Doing this will probably give you better cache coherence because it's likely that `bitMap[x-level, y]` and `bitmap[x+level, y]` will be on the same cache line, whereas it's highly unlikely that `bitmap[x-level, y]` and `bitmap[x-level, y+1]` will be on the same cache line. The savings you gain from doing the memory access that way might not be worth the add complexity in the coding.